# Txt with dates and time to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I downloaded stock exchange data and stored it in a `.txt` file. It looks like this:

```
2014-11-04  09:00:00    79.42   79.6    79.42   79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:01    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:02    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:03    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:04    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:05    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:06    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:07    79.42   79.42   79.4    79.4    
2014-11-04  09:00:08    79.4    79.4    79.4    79.4    
2014-11-04  09:00:09    79.4    79.4    79.4    79.4    
2014-11-04  09:00:10    79.4    79.4    79.4    79.4    
2014-11-04  09:00:11    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43
2014-11-04  09:00:12    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43
2014-11-04  09:00:13    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:14    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:15    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:16    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:17    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:18    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:19    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:20    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:21    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43   
2014-11-04  09:00:22    79.43   79.43   79.43   79.43
```

It is formatted as: `date | time | open | high | low | close`

In order to proces longer timeframes, I want to load this data into a numpy array.

How can I use the numpy loadtxt function to store the data in an array with separate columns, with the first and second column formatted as date and time?

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, you can do something like that:

```
strData ="""
2014-11-04  09:00:00    79.42   79.6    79.42   79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:01    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:02    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:03    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6    
2014-11-04  09:00:04    79.6    79.6    79.6    79.6  
""";
import numpy
nNbrColumn = 6;
a = strData.split()
a = numpy.reshape( a, (len(a)/nNbrColumn,nNbrColumn) );
```

But then you're stuck because numpy doesn't accept heterogenous data.

So have a look at panda, perhaps...

OR, using standard python list:

```
a = strData.split()
a = zip(*[iter(a)]*nNbrColumn)
a = [[datetime.datetime.strptime(l[0] + " " + l[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),float(l[2]),float(l[3]),float(l[4]),float(l[5])]  for l in a]
```

Comment: A numpy structured array can hold heterogeneous data.

Comment: Is it possible to load the time in a seperate numpy array in time format? By finding the index for some time, I can select the corresponding price data.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser: but you can't use datetime in structured array. Do we?

Comment: @ Willem-Jan: sure, don't hesitate to use what you prefer: [ datetime.datetime.strptime(l[0], '%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.datetime.strptime(l[1], '%H:%M:%S'), ...

Comment: @Alexandre: what does the code look like? Is it the numpy loadtxt function with a converter in Python 3?